# why does & (address) of an array print "&" in go

Tags: go

Here is the go code

```
package main 

func main() {

    var ax [2]int
    ax[0] = 22
    ax[1] = 99

    bx := ax
    cx := &ax

    fmt.Println(ax)
    fmt.Println(bx)
    fmt.Println(cx)
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", cx)

}
```

When I execute it, it gives me the following output

```
PS C:\personal\gospace> ./bin/test
[22 99]
[22 99]
&[22 99]
0xc0420381d0
```

`cx := &ax` rightly interpreted cx as pointer. But when I print cx it prints `&[22 99]` and when I print `&ax[0]` or `%p` formatter for cx it rightly prints the address. Why is this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default printing verb `fmt.Println` uses is `%v`. While printing it [differentiates](https://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go?s=7388:7437#L841) value vs pointer value, that's why you see `&` in front of `cx`.

```
fmt.Println(cx)
```

Next, you specifically tell `fmt.Printf` to use the verb `%p`, refer to [printing](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing) section and it prints `base 16 notation, with leading 0x`.

```
fmt.Printf("%p\n", cx)
```