# Golang image ColorModel()

Tags: image, go, colors

I am teaching myself Go. I decided to try some computer vision stuff. First things first I was going to make an image histogram. I'm trying to get the color model so I know the intensity range of the pixels. When I print `image.ColorModel()` it gives me a cryptic hexidecimal output:

`color model:  &{0x492f70}`

I couldn't find any explanation in the docs. I was expecting some sort of enum type thing that would map to a color model like, NRGBA, RGBA, etc.

What does that hexidecimal mean? What does the ampersand curly braces `&{...}` mean? Also what is the "N" in NRGBA I can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To extend putu's answer, comparing the returned color model to the "prepared" models of the [`image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/) package only works if one of those models is used, else all comparison will result in `false`. Also it is quite inconvenient to list and compare to all possible models.

Instead to find out a talkative form of the color model, we may use this little trick: try to convert any color using the color model of the image. A concrete color model converts all color values (implementations) to the color type / implementation used by the image. Printing the type of the resulting color will tell you what you are looking for.

Example:

```
col := color.RGBA{} // This is the "any" color we convert
var img image.Image

img = &image.NRGBA{}
fmt.Printf("%T\n", img.ColorModel().Convert(col))

img = &image.Gray16{}
fmt.Printf("%T\n", img.ColorModel().Convert(col))

img = &image.NYCbCrA{}
fmt.Printf("%T\n", img.ColorModel().Convert(col))

img = &image.Paletted{}
fmt.Printf("%T\n", img.ColorModel().Convert(col))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nLpXPe-h4l)):

```
color.NRGBA
color.Gray16
color.NYCbCrA
<nil>
```

As can be seen, an image of type [`*image.NRGBA`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#NRGBA) models colors using [`color.NRGBA`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#NRGBA), an image of type [`*image.Gray16`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Gray16) models colors using [`color.Gray16`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#Gray16) etc. As a last example I used [`*image.Paletted`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Paletted), where the result was `nil`, because the image's palette was empty.

To quickly fix the `nil` palette, let's provide an initial palette:

```
img = &image.Paletted{Palette: []color.Color{color.Gray16{}}}
fmt.Printf("%T\n", img.ColorModel().Convert(col))
```

Now the output will be (try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/N8MaWzDCc2)):

```
color.Gray16
```

Comment: Thank you, interesting approach, and yes it is more robust.

Answer (score 6):

An [`Image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Image) is declared as an interface having the following method sets:

```
type Image interface {
    ColorModel() color.Model
    Bounds() Rectangle
    At(x, y int) color.Color
}
```

Method `ColorModel()` returns an interface named [`color.Model`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#Model) which is declared as:

```
type Model interface {
    Convert(c Color) Color
}
```

Since the `ColorModel` returns an interface, you can't dereference it using `*`. What you see as `&{0x492f70}` is the underlying data structure which implements `color.Model` interface, and in this case, it is a pointer which points to address `0x492f70`. Usually, it doesn't matter how `ColorModel`'s underlying data is implemented (any type is valid as long as it has `Convert(c Color) Color` method), but if you're curious, the models for several standard color types are implemented as a pointer to [*unexported* struct](https://golang.org/src/image/color/color.go?s=3098:3146#L156) declared as:

```
type modelFunc struct {
    f func(Color) Color
}
```

What you got when you print the `ColorModel` is a pointer to this struct. Try print it using `fmt.Printf("%+v\n", img.ColorModel())`, you will see an output likes `&{f:0x492f70}`, in which `f` denotes the field name in the above struct.

In [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#Model), there are several models for the standard color types, e.g. `color.NRGBAModel`, `color.GrayModel`, etc. If you want to detect the image's color model, you can compare it to these standard models, e.g.

```
if img.ColorModel() == color.RGBAModel {
    //32-bit RGBA color, each R,G,B, A component requires 8-bits
} else if img.ColorModel() == color.GrayModel {
    //8-bit grayscale
}
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

> What does that hexidecimal mean?

Memory pointer address of the variable you're printing.

> What does the ampersand curly braces &{...} mean?

Refer to this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44641834/1343356)

> what is the "N" in NRGBA

NRGBA represents a non-alpha-premultiplied 32-bit color. Refer to [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#NRGBA).

Comment: I figured it was a memory address, but how do I get the color model that it represents. I tried dereferencing with `*` but that gave me an error.

Comment: You can use `*` to dereference it. Can you share the error info?

Comment: When I use `*(src.color.Model())` I get: `src/github/see/histogram/histogram.go:13: invalid indirect of src.ColorModel() (type color.Model)`

Comment: Just do either one `*src.color.Model()` or `(*src.color.Model())`.